# Algebraic number spaces

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, vector-spaces

While studying about Vector spaces and subspaces I came across the following question:-

$Q.$ Do $algebraic$ numbers form a subspace of the vector space $\Bbb R$?

According to my knowledge of $algebraic$ numbers, I am aware that they are the roots of polynomials with integral coefficients. So $i$ should also be an $algebraic$ number. Hence the question is wrong unless I am wrong (probably the latter).

Assuming that the question is correct, how would I prove that algebraic numbers are closed under addition?

For scalar multiplication, though, I have the following idea. Let there be any algebraic real number $x$. We look at the quantity $\frac{\pi}x$ which is real and hence a scalar. Now if we multiply $\frac{\pi}x$ to $x$ then we get $\pi$.Here we take the $x$ as a vector. So after carrying out scalar multiplication we see that the result is not an $algebraic$ number. Hence the set of $algebraic$ numbers is not closed under scalar multiplication. Hence the set of $algebraic$ numbers is not a subspace of $\Bbb R$.

Is my proof correct? Also I have no idea about what to do with closure over addition... so I would like to have a hint about it first.

Comment: If it is not closed under scalar multiplication it is not a subspace. It doesn't matter if it is closed under addition.

Comment: Wait a minute, are you regarding $\Bbb R$ as vector space over $\Bbb R$ or over $\Bbb Q$? It makes quite a difference.

Comment: Are you using $x$ to represent two different things?  A scalar and a vector?

Comment: I am saying that if $x$ is real then it may belong to both the field and the space. I am taking it once as a scalar and then as a vector.

Comment: @LeBtz: I know that very well but any way I would like to know if it is closed under addition. The proof might help somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

If the field of scalars is $\mathbb{Q}$, then yes the algebraic numbers are a subspace of the $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space $\mathbb{R}$.

If the field of scalars is $\mathbb{R}$, then the answer is no: the algebraic numbers aren't closed under scalar multiplication, because $1$ is an algebraic number but $e\cdot 1=e$ is not.

Comment: Could you please prove the closure property of algebraic numbers over addition over $\Bbb R$ (irrespctive of other conditions..)? I will upvote your answer once you include this part in your answer..

Comment: This is most easily proved via field theory: if $\alpha,\beta$ are algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$, then $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta)$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, hence all of its elements are algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$. In particular, $\alpha+\beta$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I asked it over $\Bbb R$ not over $\Bbb Q$. Please prove or disprove closure over addition of algebraic numbers over $\Bbb R$ as a field.

Comment: For $\Bbb Q$ even i can prove it. For example, if $\alpha, \beta$ are rationals, then $\alpha+\beta$ is also a rational, say $\frac pq$. Then $px-q=0$ is the polynomial whose root is $\alpha+\beta$.

Comment: The scalar field doesn't matter when proving closure under addition.

Comment: I am talking about the vector space $\Bbb R$. Please feel free to point out whenever you think I am mistaking between the vector space and scalar field. I am a newcomer to this area of maths.